# Android: Getting Google Cast MediaRouter Icon to Show

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm trying to test out some stuff with Chromecast, but running into issues getting the MediaRouter button to show up in the action bar. I've already registered my device with the cast dev console, manifest has play services/internet permission, and I've been following along with the documentation.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private MediaRouteSelector mSelector;
private MediaRouter mMediaRouter;


private final MediaRouter.Callback mMediaRouterCallback =
        new MediaRouter.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRoutePresentationDisplayChanged(
                    MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {

            }
        };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance( this );

    mSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    mMediaRouter.addCallback(mSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
            MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
    super.onStop();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);

    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider =
            (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(
                    mediaRouteMenuItem);

    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mSelector);

    return true;
}

}
```

Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<item android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="Chromecast"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
</menu>
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:19.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Try to make the following change to your selector; change it to:

```
mSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder().addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID)).build();
```

and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that you registered with the dev console, but did you enable the cast device to send its serial number when checking for updates?

Comment: Since he is using the default receiver, there is no need to have any sort of device registration.